# file/after hook executed twice with listings and LaTeX 2020-10-01 PL3

Tags: listings, lthooks

This morning after an update to LaTeX 2020-10-01 PL3 my [test suite failed with a mysterious error](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/runs/1633073341?check_suite_focus=true).

The error could be traced back to a not-so-minimal WE of the following form

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\lstset{escapeinside = {(*@}{@*)},}
\newtcblisting{mylisting}{listing only}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{mylisting}
(*@1@*)
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}
(*@2@*)
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}
(*@3@*)
\end{mylisting}
 
\begin{mylisting}
(*@4@*)
\end{mylisting}
 
\begin{mylisting}
(*@5@*)
\end{mylisting}
 
\begin{mylisting}
(*@6@*)
\end{mylisting}

\begin{mylisting}
(*@7@*)
\end{mylisting}
\end{document}
```

which fails with

```
Package scrlfile-hook Warning: More file names popped from stack than put to.
(scrlfile-hook)                This should never happen. However, it could
(scrlfile-hook)                happen if scrlfile-hook is loaded by another
(scrlfile-hook)                package or class. In this case some packages or
(scrlfile-hook)                classes are not recognised correctly.
 
(./scrlfile-escaped-listings-tcolorbox.listing)
\openout4 = `scrlfile-escaped-listings-tcolorbox.listing'.
 
 
(./scrlfile-escaped-listings-tcolorbox.listing)
 
! LaTeX3 Error: Message 'to-much-pops' for module 'scrlfile-hook' already
(LaTeX3)        defined.
 
For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
 
l.39 \end{mylisting}
 
? 
 
Package scrlfile-hook Warning: More file names popped from stack than put to.
(scrlfile-hook)                This should never happen. However, it could
(scrlfile-hook)                happen if scrlfile-hook is loaded by another
(scrlfile-hook)                package or class. In this case some packages or
(scrlfile-hook)                classes are not recognised correctly.
```

At first I thought this was a KOMA-Script problem, so I asked about the issue at https://komascript.de/node/2362, but it turns out that even though the problem really only became apparent due to a slight oversight in KOMA-Script (which has already been fixed); the core of the problem goes deeper.

The following MWE shows that the `file/after` hook code may end up being executed several times in certain circumstances.
Since KOMA-Script's `filehook` module uses `file/after` to pop a stack of file names, the hook may end up popping several files at once causing the warning and ultimately the error from above.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapeinside = {(*@}{@*)},}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AddToHook{file/before}{\AfterPreamble{A [\CurrentFile]}}
\AddToHook{file/after}{\AfterPreamble{Z}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-normal.tex}
Lorem
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-escaped.tex}
(*@ipsum@*)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{\jobname-normal.tex}

\lstinputlisting{\jobname-escaped.tex}

\lstinputlisting{\jobname-normal.tex}

\lstinputlisting{\jobname-escaped.tex}
\end{document}
```

The code runs without errors, but in the output we can see that the `file/after` code is executed twice for the listings containing an `escapeinside` sequence.

[image: LoremZ//ipsumZZ]

Unfortunately, the circumstances in which the hook is run twice seem to be rather hard to pin down.

Relevant package versions are

```
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 3
L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03>
listings 2020/03/24 1.8d
```

all examples work fine on my MikTeX system, which runs LaTeX 2020-10-01 PL2.

Why does the file hook get executed twice here and how can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: well tcolorbox is out, I can reproduce it with \lstinputlisting alone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Nevermind, got it. Thanks for the hint. I will edit the question shortly.

Comment: I have a simpler example: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56612339#56612339

Comment: @moewe Thanks for finding this.  It is indeed a bug introduced in the new version when `\CurrentFile` is cleared within the file.  That should rarely happen, but it's not impossible, as Ulrike's example shows.  This patch should fix the problem: https://pastebin.com/raw/bvp9Wf80

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, that patch seems to resolve the issue both in my large document as well as the small test cases I came up with while isolating the problem. Thank you very much for the thorough investigation and the quick fix.

Comment: Now also at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/464

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Now that PL4 is out do you want to type up a quick answer that I can accept?

Comment: @moewe Done.  Thanks for finding this issue! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When inputting a file with `\InputIfFileExists` (basically what is used everywhere across LaTeX, except for a few special cases like the plain syntax `\input <file>`), it sets the `\CurrentFile`, uses the hooks `file/before` and `file/before/\CurrentFile`, then reads the file in, then uses `file/after/\CurrentFile` and `file/after`.

The problem with that, is that if while reading the file the macro `\CurrentFile` was changed, for whatever reason, the `file/after/\CurrentFile` hook executed would be wrong.  In your case, as Ulrike found out, it was that a group started outside the file, and ended inside it, so local assignments were lost, and `\CurrentFile` was reset to empty, so the hook used was `file/after/`.  On top of that, a bad design of a sanitisation macro dropped the final `/`, so the hook used was `file/after`, and then `file/after` again.

This was taken into account in previous versions (`\CurrentFile` was consistently restored after `\@@input` was finished), but a bug introduced with [this commit](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/fc36d24b) (part of PL3) delayed restoring `\CurrentFile` to after the hooks were executed, which is kind of pointless.

I fixed this issue in [this pull request](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/467), part of PL4.  If you are reading this and experiencing this issue, update your LaTeX.